# Creating a Count if in VBA

Tags: vba

I wrote a quick script to sum everything in column E if everything is equal in column A, C, and D. I am getting an error and the actual sum function isn't working. Do you know why this would be happeing?

```
For i = 36 To 714 Step 1
Count = 0
If Cells(i, 7) <> 1 Then
    x = i + 1
    Do While x <> 714
        Count = Cells(i, 5)
            If Cells(i, 1) = Cells(x, 1) And Cells(i, 3) = Cells(x, 3) And Cells(i, 4) = Cells(x, 4) Then
                Cells(x, 7) = 1
                Count = Count + Cells(x, 5)
            End If
        x = x + 1
    Loop
    Cells(i, 6) = Count
End If
```

Next

Comment: Which error are you getting and at which line?

Comment: I figured out why it was not compiling. I am now having trouble getting the count variable to sum from E and then print it out. Why would this bee happening?

Comment: Are you trying to sum (e.g.) A36, C36, and D36 if they're all equal? And if they are equal, are you then trying to count the number of rows that contain matches?

Answer (score 0):

As long as i reaches 714, x becomes 715 which is not equal to 714 and then do while loop stuck with eternal x. Use <= instead.